# Best StackExchange Website for Programming Question

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

I have some specific programming questions like what command should be used in a certain situation or questions like how do I do X with Y. Which Stack website would be the best? I am thinking https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Both your examples seem too technical for Programmers. Did you happen to read the [site's FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq)?

Comment: From the very generic examples, StackOverflow seems like the correct place for those questions.

Comment: I feel that my programming questions are specific "How can I easily play OGG files in Python3.3, not Python2?". I have read the site's FAQ, very helpful by the way. I feel that my question would work well under the category "algorithm and data structure concepts", but yet my questions may be specific to me and not benefit others.

Comment: Are your questions about program design, before you have started writing code? You are still at the whiteboard stage and then Programmers is the place to ask. If you are coding and have trouble getting it to work, then you want to ask on Stack Overflow. Roughly.

Comment: Your examples are extremely generic, but in general you can keep in mind that when a question has a clear "How do I..." nature that can be answered with a singular "Well like this..." response, it belong on Stack Overflow. The OGG files question falls in this format.

Comment: I have done most of the programming. I just want to polish up the code and add other features. Other questions I have are like "What is Python3's equivalent to BASH's command XXX?"

Comment: So does everyone agree that StackOverflow is the best option, if so post it as an answer so that I can mark your answer as best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example question (How do I do X with Y) sounds like you are seeking code-specific help, so that would be more appropriate to post on Stack Overflow

If you were asking for more conceptual code help, than Programmers would be more appropriate.

To quote from the Programmer's [meta post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/171/1130) about the difference between StackOverflow and Programmers:

> In a nutshell, **Stack Overflow is for when you’re front of your compiler or editor** working through code issues. **Programmers is for when you’re in front of a whiteboard** working through higher level conceptual programming issues.
>
> Stated another way, Stack Overflow questions almost all have **actual source code in the questions or answers**. It’s much rarer (though certainly OK) for a Programmers question to contain source code.

Comment: Thank you all for all of the help.